# ssh config Host wildcards and fully-qualified names

Tags: openssh

I have a `~/.ssh/config` file that looks like this:

```
Host server*
    HostName %h.farm.example.com
```

When I `ssh server01`, it connects to `server01.farm.example.com` correctly.

But when I `ssh server01.farm.example.com`, it attempts to connect to `server01.farm.example.com.farm.example.com`.

The second form is used by certain of our deployment scripts, so I don't really have any options.

How do I get `server*` to not match on fully-qualified names?

Comment: You could also add `search farm.example.com` to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: No, the full form is used by scripts, so he can't always use the short form.

Answer (score 4):

Include a Host entry which matches the fully-qualified name, setting the hostname to %h. If you put it before the existing rule, it will take precedence.

```
Host server*.farm.example.com
    HostName %h

Host server*
    HostName %h.farm.example.com
```